# Centos 7 / MariaDB, 1gig DigitalOcean Droplet high traffic kills MySQL

Tags: mysql, centos7, mariadb, digital-ocean

I have a Centos 7 / MariaDB, 1gig DigitalOcean Droplet with 2 low traffic Wordpress sites on. When the server gets approx 15 concurrent users MySQL runs out of memory and drops. Log below:

```
180806 14:43:05 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the 
buffer pool
180806 14:43:05 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
180806 14:43:05 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
180806 14:43:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
180806 14:43:05 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
180806 14:43:05 [ERROR] Aborting

180806 14:43:05 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

So my question here is, what can i do to stop MySQL from dropping, Apache stays up fine. So hoping some handy configuration tweaks will resolve this for me :)

Cheers all!

Comment: This is one of our more frequently asked questions. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @devools  Post on pastebin.com or here. A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for  analysis and meaningful suggestions will be prepared for you, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your server has limited RAM and you are probably allocating way too much memory to MySQL connections.
I would suggest to review MySQL configuration and reduce buffers size.

An easy way to verify MySQL configuration and memory allocation is to run [mysqltuner](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl) or another free tool.

Comment: Also look at options reducing the apache footprint. Or not using apache and using nginx. Or using sqlite rather than mysql. Overall 1G is a tiny amount of ram to be running a service.